# Using fetchmail for one time email extraction from gmail

Tags: fetchmail

- I'm trying to use `fetchmail` in terminal to extract e-mails from my gmail account.
- I configured my `~/.fetchmailrc` with:

```
poll imap.gmail.com protocol POP3
   user "someuser@gmail.com" is oren here
   password 'verysecretpassword'
```

(Of course with real username+password).

- Then I tried to naively extract emails with: `$ fetchmail`.
- Sadly nothing happened, and all I got was:

```
fetchmail: 6.3.26 querying imap.gmail.com (protocol POP3) at Mon 03 Feb 2020 14:34:46 IST: poll started
Trying to connect to <ADDRESS> ... connection failed.
```

Comment: How determined are you to use fetchmail for this? It might be easier with a different tool, if you have the option to pick something else.

Comment: @Z4-tier not very determined -- please suggest any other option ...

Answer (score 6):

**Using Fetchmail**

It looks like the config is set to poll an IMAP server but then specifying POP3 protocol. Try something like this for the `~/.fetchmailrc` file:

```
set postmaster "local_user"
set daemon 600
poll pop.gmail.com with proto POP3
   user 'gmail_user_name' there with password 'app_password' is local_user here options ssl fetchlimit 400
```

where:

- `local_user` is some local account where undeliverable mail should go (the "last ditch effort" before failing permanently).
- `gmail_user_name` is everything to the left of the `@` in the email address.
- `app_password` is a specially generated password that is restricted to the gmail application (go here: https://myaccount.google.com/ and click `Security`, then `app passwords` and generate a new app password)

What to do at this point will depend on your local setup. Fetchmail will... fetch mail (clearly).... and then deliver it to the local machine's delivery system. If you have sendmail (a pretty safe bet), this might work:

```
$ fetchmail -d0 -avNk -m "/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -f %F -- %T" pop.gmail.com
```

Mail should start flowing in. Messages can be read using the `mail` command or get the raw content from `/var/mail/[username]`. This might not get everything in one shot; it very likely won't if the address has accumulated even a small amount of history. Let it finish and check that it worked as expected. If everything looks good, then it's time to start `fetchmail` as a daemon process and let it download the entire mailbox. First, configure `fetchmail` with appropriate polling interval and batch size settings<sup>1</sup>.

- Confirm that the polling interval is configured in the `~/.fetchmailrc` by the line `daemon 600` (ie. 10 minute polling interval).
- Confirm that the polling option `fetchlimit 400` is set in the `~/.fetchmailrc` under the `options` section in the `poll pop.gmail.com` stanza. This is the maximum number of messages to fetch per poll.
- Start fetchmail using the same command as above, **but omit the `-d0` switch**.

Fetchmail should start as a true daemon and continue to periodically download batches of messages until the whole mailbox is downloaded. You will need to remember to kill the daemon process if you don't want it to continue syncing until the next reboot.

---

**Using Google Takeout**

You can do this super easy using [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/). Log in, click the "deselect" option at the top of the list, then scroll down to `Mail` and check just that. You can choose to get the data in a `.zip` or `.tgz` file. They will send you an email when the archive is ready for download. It is packaged in an `mbox` file but that is pretty straightforward to convert to other formats.

This is probably the easiest way to accomplish a one time export, and I think they have an option to set up a recurring export too. It probably isn't offering as much control compared to using the developer API directly, but it's a lot less hassle.

---

<sub>1: I believe Google has some rate limiting in place, so I am adding some steps to accommodate those limits. These are conservative values, since I don't know exactly what the limits are (or even for sure if they exist). If you know more, or care to research it, adjust these values to whatever you think is best.</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately the fechmail doesn't work :(( ... I need a solution from terminal, it doesn't have to be fetchmail, but from what I see, Google Takeout must involve a human pressing buttons in some GUI right? are there any other options?

Comment: My mistake, the `-m` options (so all of `/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -f %F -- %T`) should be enclosed in double quotes. I updated the answer. This works for me on MacOS Mojave, but i would expect it to work on most sane (ie. not alpine) Linux/BSD variants as well. If it still doesn't work, can you update the question with the error output that gets generated?

Comment: I updated this with all the necessary details to make `fetchmail` work. Note some changes to the `~/.fetchmailrc` file and to the command used to invoke `fetchmail`.

Comment: It takes an incredible amount of time to download a single email. I think GMail is not signaling that the transfer has finished?

Comment: Is fetchmail still possible with gmail? In https://myaccount.google.com/security I saw a message, that since may 30th 2022 3rd-party logins are not supported anymore if the client only allow username&password

Comment: Obviously, OAuth2 is the problem. Here's a nice article about it including a solution (but I didn't test it): http://billauer.co.il/blog/2022/06/fetchmail-gmail-lsa-oauth2/

Comment: @DanielAlder Good info, it looks like you're right. Unless providers start implementing OAuth2 in more portable manner, it sounds like fetchmail is not going to officially integrate support for it.